# Looking for some abelian surface fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Do you know of any  explicit smooth complex projective threefold $X$ with an Abelian surface fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1$ such that $K_X = [-F]$ where $F$ is the fiber class divisor.

I am not looking for examples which are fiber product of two elliptic fibrations.

Comment: Well, there goes my idea then. I was going to suggest a fibration $E \to S$ with $S$ a rational elliptic surface...